# Ruby , I couldn't find how the following code actually works

Tags: ruby

```
class ArrayMine < Array

  def join( sep = $,, format = "%s" )

    collect do |item|
      sprintf( format, item )
    end.join( sep )
  end

end

=> rooms = ArrayMine[3, 4, 6]    #i couldn't understand how this line works

print "We have " + rooms.join( ", ", "%d bed" ) + " rooms available."
```

i have tried the same with String, but it comes up with an error.

```
    thank you...
```

Answer (score 4):

ArrayMine inherits from Array and you can initialize Ruby arrays like that.

```
>> rooms = Array[3,4,6]
=> [3, 4, 6]
```

is the same as

```
>> rooms = [3,4,6]
=> [3, 4, 6]
```

Also the quite strange looking `def join( sep = $,, format = "%s" )`
 is using the [pre-defined variable](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Variables_and_Constants#Pre-defined_Variables) `$,` that is the output field separator for the print and `Array#join`.

It could also have been done like this

```
rooms=["b",52,"s"]
print "We have " + rooms.map{|s| s.to_s+" bed"}.join(", ") + " rooms available."
```

The reason you can't do what you are trying to do with `String` is because assignment is not a class method but [] on `Array` is. Just `new` it instead.

```
>> s = Substring.new("abcd")
=> "abcd"
>> s.checking_next
=> "abce"
```

You can't override assignment in Ruby, it's only so that setter methods looks like assignment but they are actually method calls and as such they can be overridden.
If you are feeling like being tricky and still want a similar behaviour as `a=SubArray[1,2,3]` you could create a `<<` [class method](http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/) something like this:

```
class Substring < String
  def next_next()
    self.next().next() 
  end
  def self.<<(val)
    self.new(val)
  end
end 

>> sub = Substring<<"abcb"
=> "abcb"
>> sub.next_next
=> "abcd"
>> sub<<" the good old <<"
=> "abcb the good old <<"
>> sub.class<<"this is a new string"
=> "this is a new string"
```

Comment: yep thanks.... but why the same is not working with string...i created sub class of string and tried to initialize,it doesn't work....... thanks man  (string = Subclass_of_String"hello") 
it works fine with String class..

Comment: i took this from why's poignant guide to ruby.... its really awesome
u can find lots of strange examples like this...

Comment: class Substring < String;
  
  def checking_next()
    
    self.next()
   
   end;
end;

 # i have just passed the arguments same as that of array;  

obj = Substring"a";
 
p obj.checking_next;

Comment: You have no method call between `Substring` and `"a"` and there is no method call to override for assignments in Ruby. Setter methods looks a whole lot like an assignment (using = and all) but they are still just method calls and as such they can be overridden.

Answer (score 1):

For String, change `%d bed` to `%s bed`

```
irb(main):053:0> rooms = ArrayMine["a","b","c"]
=> ["a", "b", "c"]

irb(main):055:0> print "We have " + rooms.join( ", ", "%s bed" ) + " rooms available."
We have a bed, b bed, c bed rooms available.=> nil
```

Answer (score 1):

You're just invoking a `[]` class method:

```
class Spam
  def self.[]( *args )
    p args
  end
end
```

```
>> Spam[3,4,5]
[3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: @gsmuralee If the question has been answered, could you click the check on the best answer?